# Git hook within Gitkraken ignores exit code

Tags: git, cygwin, githooks, gitkraken

I try to set up a first simple pre-commit hook on a project on windows but I don't manage to stop the commit using exit code. I use Gitkraken and it runs cygwin as shell.
The pre-commit file contains the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "OK THAT line works..." > test.log
exit 1
```

When commiting, it generates the log file but the commit is not blocked by the return code.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found by myself with a colleague. In case someone run into the problem.
The `Path to sh` parameter for Gitkraken has to be set to cygwin but with the `-i` option:
    C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i

edit: or simpler with c:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe